# Uppercase C With Cedilla char (gsm 03.38 alphabet) in Iphone text message

Tags: php, iphone, gsm

I try to explain my question :

I've developed a software in php which sends text messages in gsm 03.38 charset (hex format).

When I send the "uppercase c char with cedilla" ( Ç ) ( gsm 03.38 code 09, iso-8859-1 code C7). Andorid phones show what it has to be, but iphone shows it in lowercase format ( ç ).

And i tested it from my phone (nokia 1100). I've sent Ç char from nokia 1100 to iphone. Iphone showed it in lowecase format again.

How can i fix this or what i am missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, and based on modem testing experience, my guess is a bug in the phone's firmware.  See [this post](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3672) from the Apple support forum.

The problem description is not quite the same, but there is a priceless quote half way down the page:

"Follow these tips ....
..■Try to limit use of non-ASCII characters and symbols"

A similar problem is described [in a google forum here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/voice/VkrfOxq-kdM).